# Which columns in index when used in partition and order

Tags: postgresql, performance, indexing, query-optimization

I have a table in postgres which contains following columns:

col1 varchar(50),
col2 int(10),
col3 timestamp,
col4 timestamp,
col5, 6, 7, etc.
Columns 1 to 4 are used as follow:

`select col1,..., col7, row_number() over (partition by col1, col2 order by col3 DESC, col4 DESC) from table1`

| QUERY PLAN Explain Analyze |
| --- |
| WindowAgg (cost=2368579.85..2552412.63 rows=7353311 width=95) (actual time=31385.456..40049.159 rows=7430314 loops=1) |
| -> Sort (cost=2368579.85..2386963.13 rows=7353311 width=87) (actual time=31385.407..36728.946 rows=7430314 loops=1) |
| Sort Key: col1, col2, col3 DESC, col4 DESC |
| Sort Method: external merge Disk: 230136kB |
| -> Seq Scan on table1 (cost=0.00..826198.11 rows=7353311 width=87) (actual time=0.898..9786.156 rows=7430314 loops=1) |
| Planning Time: 0.048 ms |
| Execution Time: 40402.346 ms |

| QUERY PLAN Verbose |
| --- |
| WindowAgg (cost=2368579.85..2552412.63 rows=7353311 width=111) |
| Output: 1, 2, 3, 4, row_number() OVER (?), col3, col4, col1, col2 |
| -> Sort (cost=2368579.85..2386963.13 rows=7353311 width=87) |
| Output: col3, col4, col1, col2 |
| Sort Key: col1, col2, col3 DESC, col4 DESC |
| -> Seq Scan on table1 (cost=0.00..826198.11 rows=7353311 width=87) |
| Output: col3, col4, col1, col2 |

| QUERY PLAN Buffer |
| --- |
| WindowAgg (cost=2368579.85..2552412.63 rows=7353311 width=111) (actual time=33454.895..41543.816 rows=7430314 loops=1) |
| Buffers: shared hit=17321 read=735344, temp read=74925 written=75074 |
| I/O Timings: read=7119455.865 |
| -> Sort (cost=2368579.85..2386963.13 rows=7353311 width=87) (actual time=33454.848..36846.150 rows=7430314 loops=1) |
| Sort Key: col1, col2, col3 DESC, col4 DESC |
| Sort Method: external merge Disk: 230136kB |
| Buffers: shared hit=17321 read=735344, temp read=74925 written=75074 |
| I/O Timings: read=7119455.865 |
| -> Seq Scan on table1 (cost=0.00..826198.11 rows=7353311 width=87) (actual time=1.128..12384.980 rows=7430314 loops=1) |
| Buffers: shared hit=17321 read=735344 |
| I/O Timings: read=7119455.865 |
| Planning Time: 0.068 ms |
| Execution Time: 42190.546 ms |

How should I index my table to get the best read result? And what kind of index do you suggest to use?

Update: Updated the query and query plan.

Comment: What is the full query? Indexes are designed for queries, not for a single line or two from it

Comment: for index related questions is always best to post the table structure, indexes, and the query plan (e.g. explain analyse).

Comment: Could you please share the results from explain (analyze, verbose, buffers) for your SQL statement? And please use plain text, as an update to the original question. The complete SQL statement and the DDL for tables and indexes involved, would be helpful as well. Currently it's not even sure if you have a problem at all...

Comment: The syntax "over( partition ... order ...)" does not use an index. See [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html). *The rows considered by a window function are those of the “virtual table” produced by the query's FROM clause as filtered by its WHERE, GROUP BY, and HAVING clauses if any. For example, a row removed because it does not meet the WHERE condition is not seen by any window function.* In other words the data is already in memory using index, even if possible,  would be vastly slower.

Comment: You may want to look at your **work mem** value as your query is performing a disk sort. [That's bad](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/tune-sorting-operations-in-postgresql-with-work_mem/). *If sorting requires more than the allocated work_mem, it leads to physical I/O operation, namely, having to write to temporary files on disk, which is expensive and degrades the performance of the query.*